# How to apply external styles to data join in D3?

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I'm a newbie to D3.js.  I'm following along with this tutorial: https://observablehq.com/@d3/lets-make-a-bar-chart

Essentially the tutorial is making a very simple bar chart with 6 data elements.  I have two solutions, one works and one doesn't.  First, here is my code:

[image: HTML/CSS]

[image: JS]

The code I have written here works perfectly.  However, I thought I would try something different and apply external styles.  When I uncomment the CSS from the  tag, uncomment the added class name from the JS file, and comment out the styling I did in the JS file, none of the styles apply.  Can anybody shed some light onto why the styles are not applying when I do this?

Comment: Generally adding code, instead of screenshots of code, will garner better answers and reception. For your issue, try adding the class attribute to the divs you add with `selectAll()`, you currently aren't doing anything with the `chartContainer` div so there is nothing to apply the style to.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the parent `div` selector to do your `join` otherwise you're selecting the parent `div` and merging it without the original `class` name.

so on our code just do replace

```js
d3.selectAll('div') with
```

```js
chartContainer.selectAll('div')
```

Here is one example

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<div id="c">
</div>

<style>
  .container {
    font-size: 2em;
    font-wieght: bold;
  }
</style>
<script>
  const data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

  const chart = d3.create("div");
  chart.attr('class', 'container');
  chart.selectAll('div')
    .data(data)
    .join('div')
    .text(d=> d)

  document.querySelector("#c").append(chart.node())
</script>
```